# how to display child ul right next to parent ul

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you see in my code, where I have five parent links and each link have 12 child links. The way I wanted to show my child links right next to parent link when it's selected and other child links of other parent links should be hidden at the same time. The navigation on [the telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/investigations/) website is exactly what I want.

This is the sample code of navigation.

```
  <div class="menu_container">
  <nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Menu 1">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.1">SubMenu 1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.2">SubMenu 1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.3">SubMenu 1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.4">SubMenu 1.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.5">SubMenu 1.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.6">SubMenu 1.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.7">SubMenu 1.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.8">SubMenu 1.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.9">SubMenu 1.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.10">SubMenu 1.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.11">SubMenu 1.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.12">SubMenu 1.12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Menu 2">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.1">SubMenu 2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.2">SubMenu 2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.3">SubMenu 2.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.4">SubMenu 2.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.5">SubMenu 2.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.6">SubMenu 2.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.7">SubMenu 2.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.8">SubMenu 2.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.9">SubMenu 2.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.10">SubMenu 2.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.11">SubMenu 2.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 2.12">SubMenu 2.12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Menu 3">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.1">SubMenu 3.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.2">SubMenu 3.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.3">SubMenu 3.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.4">SubMenu 3.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.5">SubMenu .5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.6">SubMenu 35.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.7">SubMenu 3.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.8">SubMenu 3.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.9">SubMenu 3.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.10">SubMenu 3.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.11">SubMenu 3.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 3.12">SubMenu 3.12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Menu 4">Menu 4</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.1">SubMenu 4.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.2">SubMenu 4.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.3">SubMenu 4.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.4">SubMenu 4.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.5">SubMenu 4.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.6">SubMenu 4.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.7">SubMenu 4.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.8">SubMenu 4.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.9">SubMenu 4.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.10">SubMenu 4.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.11">SubMenu 4.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 4.12">SubMenu 4.12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Menu 5">Menu 5</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.1">SubMenu 5.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.2">SubMenu 5.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.3">SubMenu 5.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.4">SubMenu 5.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.5">SubMenu 5.5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.6">SubMenu 5.6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.7">SubMenu 5.7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.8">SubMenu 5.8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.9">SubMenu 5.9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.10">SubMenu 5.10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.11">SubMenu 5.11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#SubMenu 5.12">SubMenu 5.12</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>
```

I am already using JQuery so any solution with JQuery is also most welcome and, of course, any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best done using `show()` and `hide()` with some DOM querying :

```
var currentParent = null;

$('.menu>ul>li>ul').hide();
$('.menu>ul>li').on('click', selectParent);

function selectParent(event) {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (currentParent && !elem.is(currentParent)) {
        currentParent.children('ul').hide();
    }

    elem.children('ul').show();

    currentParent = elem;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ebc545m2/1/) for experimenting. It also shows how you can reproduce the looks of the Telegraph's navbar using `float` and `display: inline` without modifying your markup.

However I would strongly suggest adding a second `<nav>` element under `#menu_container` that will hold submenus. You can then link parent `li` elements to `ul` sublists using the `href` and `id` attributes in the selection handler.

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#menu_1">Menu 1</a>
    <li><a href="#menu_2">Menu 2</a>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>

<nav class="submenu">
  <ul id="#menu_1">
    <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.1">SubMenu 1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.2">SubMenu 1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#SubMenu 1.3">SubMenu 1.3</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
  ...
</nav>
```

Corresponding JS :

```
var currentParent = null;
var currentSubMenu = null;

// Hide all sublists
$('.submenu>ul').hide();

$('.menu>ul>li').on('click', selectParent);

function selectParent(event) {
    var elem = $(this);

    // If there is a previous parent, hide its child list
    if (currentParent && !elem.is(currentParent)) {
        currentSubMenu.hide();
    }

    var childID = elem.children('a').attr('href');
    var childMenu = $(childID);

    // Show the clicked element's child list
    childMenu.show();

    currentParent = elem;
    currentSubMenu = childMenu;
}
```

This layout, demonstrated [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/afm2hhcd/2/), gives you much more control over the styling and allows precise positioning. In fact, that's exactly how it is done in the Telegraph's HTML (only using `div`s instead of `nav`s).

Comment: thanks for your kind answer, as you said i better go for second nav infact div that holds sublists initially this idea is also came into my mind but since i have not enough knowledge of javascript or jquery to implement that! so please can you give me one more example with jquery to implement this with second nav div!

Comment: @arcade updated my answer with an example, and a bonus fiddle.

Comment: thanks again! it works fine and what i need but still have some styling problems it shows horizontally on `jsfiddle` but in my site its shows me vertically, in first 5 menus then the sub links of clicked menu! any suggestions?

Comment: Check that you have correctly added all relevant classes and the CSS. Are you using a front-end framework like Bootstrap ?

Comment: i added all the css and i am not using Bootstrap onther framework!

Comment: ok i figure it out but one more question can i force to show first menu sublist as default?

Comment: Simulate a click event on the link you want. First get the target li : `var li = $('a[href="#submenu_1"]').parent('li');`, then do `selectParent.call(li[0]);`, binding the li element to the `this` variable.

Comment: thanks, i tried it but no luck. i probably doing it wrongly can you help me? i want 1st menu sublists to show as default!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this example - Notice the classes and places of ul's in the example on **MENU3**:

```
 $(".menu_item").hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').show();
}, 
function(){
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
});
```

[JS Example](http://jsfiddle.net/b18qdm42/2/)

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to show submenu of each menu on seperate line horizontally  right under of it and when related menu clicked. please visit this link and see navigation there [please visit](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/investigations/) this is exactly what i want!